# How to arrange items inside a popup of QML?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html

This is what I have tried. I want the inner rectangles of the Popup's Rectangle to fill up the whole area. There is some gap on the left and top side.

```
Window
{
    visible: true
    width: 1000
    height: 1000
    title: qsTr("Hello World")


    Rectangle
    {
        id: dot

        color:"blue"; radius: 100
        height: 33
        width:  33

        MouseArea
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: popup.open()
        }
    }

    Popup
    {
        id: popup;
        width: 114
        height: 88
        x: 100; y: 45
        focus: true
        closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutsideParent
       Rectangle
       {
           color: "red";
           anchors.fill: parent

           ColumnLayout
           {anchors.fill: parent
               Rectangle{ height: 30; width: 100; border.color: "black"}
               Rectangle{ height: 30; width: 100; border.color: "black"}
               Rectangle{ height: 30; width: 100; border.color: "black"}
           }
       }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be aware of `Popup` `padding` , `ColumnLayout spacing`.

The gaps are caused by the popup `padding` ... if you want no `padding` set it to 0.

But even with 0 `padding`,

You will get gap on the right ..because `popup` `width` (114) is inherited by the Popup's Rectangle but the inner rectangles are set at fixed `width` of 100 .. so the  gap of 14 appears.

If you fix that .. still you have to consider `Columnlayout` spacing .. that's not 0 by default , which can cause last rectangle to extend below Popup's Rectangle, hence Rectangle's `clip` can be used;

For example this code draws rectangles as expected.

```
Popup
{
    id: popup;
    padding: 0
    width: 114
    height: 88
    x: 100; y: 45
    focus: true
    closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutsideParent
   Rectangle
   {
       color: "red";
       anchors.fill: parent

       ColumnLayout
       {
           anchors.fill: parent
           Rectangle{ height:30; width: popup.width; border.color: "black"}
           Rectangle{ height: 30; width: popup.width; border.color: "black"}
           Rectangle{ height: 30; width: popup.width; border.color: "black"}
       }
   }
}
```

[image]

If I want to generalize the `popup` and `Columnlayout` defaults, I would consider using `contentitem` that gives the Popup's Rectangle dimensions:
for Example:

```
Popup
{
    id: popup;
    width: 114
    height: 29 * 3
    x: 100; y: 45
    focus: true
    closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutsideParent
   Rectangle
   {
       color: "red";
       anchors.fill: parent

       ColumnLayout
       {
           anchors.fill: parent
            Repeater{
                id: repeater
                model: 3
                Rectangle{ height: (popup.contentItem.height - parent.spacing*repeater.count)/repeater.count; width: popup.contentItem.width; border.color: "black"}
            }
       }
   }
}
```

[image]